# How to use cookies in Drupal?

Tags: comments, cookies

I am writing a module that allows users to put comment on each paragraph.
So in my module I have added a new field to comment table called "paragraph_id" and I have also added a new field to comment form that say:

```
 Which paragraph do you want to put comment on?
```

After each paragraph I have added a link saying:

```
  Put comment on paragraph 1 (2,3, ...., the number changed based on the number of the paragraph.
```

in order to this, I have written the following in node.tpl.php:

```
        for ($i=1;$i<$number;$i++) {

        print render($paragraphs[$i]);
       ?>

      <a href="#commenting">Put comment for Paragraph <?php echo $i?><br></a>


    <?php
```

I want to do one the following options:

1) Eliminate the new field which asks for the number of the paragraph from comment form, and do something that when a user for example clicks on a link like:

```
   Put comment on paragraph 1
```

, the number "1" automatically got save in comment table in "paragraph_id" field.

2) Or  keep the field that asks for paragraph number in comment form and when user clicks on a link like

```
 Put Comment on Paragraph 1
```

while he is getting directed to the comment form, the value of that field (paragraph_number in comment form) sets to 1.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do cookies have to do with what you want to do? Aside from the question title there is no other reference to cookies in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal automatically ensures that a user has a session, so your script can simply read and write to the [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) superglobal array.

Answer (score 0):

To set the expiration value for your website's session cookies:
Go to **Configuration > Session expiration**.

Select from the following expiration options:

1. **Default (3 weeks 2 days)** - Removes the session cookie from the user's computer 3 weeks and 2 days after creation.
2. **When the browser session is closed** - Removes the session cookie from the user's computer when the user closes their browser.
3. **After a specific period of time** - Removes the session cookie from the user's computer after an elapsed time period. Enter a time
   value that's based on your selected date unit (such as minutes or
   weeks).

Click **Save configuration**.